# Attach watir-webdriver to an existing window

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Is it possible to attach a watir-webdriver to an already opened browser window?

Comment: A corollary would be to be able to save a watir-webdriver object for a later runtime session, a feature I too have been waiting for a very long time, meanwhile experimenting using various methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watir-webdriver is built on top of selenium-webdriver, and this is a pending feature at this point.

See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: I knew it was pending since early 2010. Hoped it has been fixed by now.
Shame ! Its something that could be very useful :(

Comment: Issue has been closed as "not feasible" FYI